# Return Subquery with Multiple Columns as JSON Array of JSON Objects

Tags: postgresql, subquery, json

In my setup, the relevant tables for this problem are:

- Items
- Users
- Collections (of Items) — each user can have multiple
- Collection Items — where I track what items are in each collection.

The `items` and `users` tables are pretty much as simple as it gets, here are the `collections` and `collection_items` tables (`mi` is the name of my schema):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mi.users (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT min_length_users_name CHECK (char_length(name) >= 4),
    email VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    pic BYTEA
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mi.items (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    author_id UUID NOT NULL CONSTRAINT item_author_fk REFERENCES mi.users (id),
    title VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT min_length_items_title CHECK (char_length(title) >= 4),
    description VARCHAR(5000) CONSTRAINT min_length_items_description CHECK (char_length(description) >= 5)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mi.collections (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () CONSTRAINT collections_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    author_id UUID NOT NULL CONSTRAINT collection_author_fk REFERENCES mi.users (id),
    title VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT min_length_items_title CHECK (char_length(title) >= 4),
    description VARCHAR(5000) CONSTRAINT min_length_items_description CHECK (char_length(description) >= 5)
);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mi.collection_items (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () CONSTRAINT collection_items_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    collection_id UUID NOT NULL CONSTRAINT collection_items_collection_fk REFERENCES mi.collections (id),
    item_id UUID NOT NULL CONSTRAINT collection_items_item_id REFERENCES mi.items (id),
    CONSTRAINT you_can_only_add_an_item_once_to_a_collection UNIQUE (collection_id, item_id)
);
```

What I would like is to, when querying for a collection, also return its items, in a JSON array of JSON objects (I'm using `node-pg`, that's why there are variables with `${}`):

```sql
SELECT 
    mi.collections.created_at,
    jsonb_build_object(
        'id', mi.collections.author_id,
        'name', mi.users.name,
        'pic', mi.users.pic
    ) author,
    mi.collections.title,
    mi.collections.description,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mi.collection_items
        WHERE mi.collection_items.collection_id = '${collectionId}'
    ) AS total_items,
    -- This is where I'm trying to get it done.
    jsonb_build_array(
        SELECT 
            jsonb_build_object(
                'id', mi.items.id,
                'title', mi.items.title,
                'description', mi.items.description
            ) item
        FROM mi.collection_items
        JOIN mi.items ON mi.collection_items.item_id = mi.items.id
        WHERE mi.collection_items.collection_id = '${collectionId}'
        ORDER BY mi.collection_items.created_at DESC
        OFFSET ${offset}
        LIMIT ${paginationLimit}
    ) 
FROM mi.collections
JOIN mi.users ON mi.users.id = mi.collections.author_id
WHERE mi.collections.id = '${collectionId}'
```

The query would result in something of this shape:

```json
{
  "created_at": "2023-07-10T20:54:34.883Z",
  "title": "Title 1",
  "description": "A great description",
  "author": {
    "id": "906ca589-db0f-4c6e-add4-220cc3f2ea95",
    "name": "john",
    "pic": "\\x2f686f6d652f7068696c692f436f64652f6d61676e75735f696e6465782f6261636b656e642f6173736574732f737461636b6f766572666c6f775f7069635f312e706e67"
  },
  "total_items": 2,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "906ca589-abcd-4c6e-add4-220cc3f2ea95",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "description": "Description 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "906ca589-efgh-4c6e-add4-220cc3f2ea95",
      "title": "Title 2",
      "description": "Description 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `jsonb_build_array` to build an array out of a set of rows, it only accepts a scalar value. So you need to use `jsonb_agg` instead, within the subbquery

```sql
(
    SELECT
        jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'id', mi.items.id,
                'title', mi.items.title,
                'description', mi.items.description
            )
        )
    FROM mi.collection_items
    JOIN mi.items ON mi.collection_items.item_id = mi.items.id
    WHERE mi.collection_items.collection_id = '${collectionId}'
    ORDER BY mi.collection_items.created_at DESC
    OFFSET ${offset}
    LIMIT ${paginationLimit}
)
```

But I'd advise you to learn how to use table aliases, to make this more readable. Also, I'm not sure about your client driver, but it looks suspiciously like **dangerous** SQL injection. Furthermore, you can restrict yourself to only filtering the `collection_id` once, by using correlated predicates.

```sql
SELECT 
    c.created_at,
    jsonb_build_object(
        'id', c.author_id,
        'name', u.name,
        'pic', u.pic
    ) AS author,
    c.title,
    c.description,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mi.collection_items ci
        WHERE ci.collection_id = c.id
    ) AS total_items,
    (
        SELECT
          jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'id', i.id,
                'title', i.title,
                'description', i.description
            )
          )
        FROM mi.collection_items ci
        JOIN mi.items i ON ci.item_id = i.id
        WHERE ci.collection_id = c.id
        ORDER BY ci.created_at DESC
        OFFSET $1
        LIMIT $2
    ) AS items
FROM mi.collections c
JOIN mi.users u ON u.id = c.author_id
WHERE c.id = $3;
```

Comment: This is a personal project at this point, and it is still a little bit far from getting into production, but you're right to talk about SQL Injections. So far, I validate requests a little bit, but nothing major, but I do have plans to shield it better against attacks in the near future.

Comment: SQL injection is also about *correctness* not just security. You could get incorrect results.

Comment: I'm still getting `error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` though.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe `node-pg` isn't able to pretty-print this nested thing properly because what I get is something like `[ Object, Object ]`. But, upon printing this nested array, everything seems to be working.